# Oracle Denies Access to table from SSIS but not from TOAD/SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, ssis

I've seen this question asked, but I have not seen it answered anywhere.

I have many tables in an Oracle DB. These are tables in my schema and for which I have full permissions.

When trying to create SSIS packages in Visual Studio, I can access and pull data from most of them, but there is one for which access is to it denied when the SSIS package runs. This is a table I created in my own schema and does not seem to be different from other tables I have created in my schema.

Any ideas why some tables for which I have full permissions in TOAD/Oracle SQL Developer/SQL PLUS should be denied when attempting to pull from SSIS?

Thanks to all who respond.

Comment: Check credential in connection you use to connect Oracle

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think that is the problem. These tables are all in my own schema in Oracle, and so my own credentials should work for all of them.

Comment: Please show a COMPLETE error message/stack.

Comment: Will do. It will be a while, as I'm focused elsewhere for another couple of hours. Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: to what the others have said, verify how exactly SSIS is connecting to the Oracle database